# Implementing page controller all over rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, content-management-system

I seem to have got a little a head of myself.
I have created a Page Model and Pages controller.  The whole idea was to be able to call something like 'print :controller=>'Pages', :action=>'view', :id=>'6', :layout=>'none''

And in my application.html.erb I have a div with yield, and in the next div I would like to have the above page.

But I just can't get my head around doing this.  Anyone who understands what I am trying to do ?
As simply as I can explain this is that I am trying to store static text in a database, and being able to call it when ever I need to.  So I can store whole pages like 'hello' and 'about me' in a text field, kind of a built in cms

Trausti

Comment: Ok, I understand that you want to store Pages in the database, so far so good. But I'm not sure how it is that you want to display them. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Well actually I am a bit stumped here.  I would simply like to to cal the page and get it as a variable that I can the just display in the view.  I have added a few find operations, but as my app grows I can't add @maindiv = Page.find(1) and @rightdiv = Page.find(2) all over all controllers, can I ?

Comment: Sure, you could, but that's extremely fragile.  What happens if your seed data gets loaded in a different order during a move and your primary keys are all wrong?  

Instead use a `find_by_` method -- and incidentally, you shouldn't have all those divs in your controllers.  That's what views and layouts are for.  (Or even better, partials and helper methods.)

Comment: Well, I am actually simplifying.  I search for specific titles, not id's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're failing to grok the flexibility of Rails models.  They're just object classes.  You can use them anywhere you'd use a Ruby object.  All of that `:controller => 'blah', :action => 'yadda'` stuff is for generating or parsing URLs for the outside world.  *Inside* your app, just call on your model.

In this case, if all you want is to easily pull the content from a page with a known name, my suggestion would be to write a class method within your Page class that does the finding for you.  For instance (adjust to your own field names and needs):

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...Other stuff...

  def self.content(name)
    page = find_by_name(name)
    page.content if page
  end
end
```

Then you could just call `Page.content('about')` anywhere you needed it and it'd return the content of the 'about' page, hot and fresh for you.

Comment: oh man.  So obvious once you see it.  Thanks so much this is exactly what I needed.